# how to get the data from map by the key in android

Tags: android, serialization, dictionary

i have a problem to retrieve the data from the map with key.
here is my code.
v is vector;s object that i get from another activity.
i got the value what i want with....
System.out.println("save in map******************"+settingName); at the end but how i can the value one by one.

```
final Serializable v1 = getIntent().getSerializableExtra("v");

System.out.println("*****"+v1);
keyname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.saveas);     
saveEdit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.savebtn);  

saveEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {     
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String keysetting = keyname.getText().toString();
        System.out.println(keysetting);
        settingName.put(keysetting, v1);                    
    }
});
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
settingName.get(keyname.getText());
```

Comment: in my v1 [false, dfg, fgd, true, false]
this type of value are there i want to store all in the seperatyely in the string. help me.

Comment: Just put more Extras to the intent. One for each variable. This would be the best solution for your problem.

Comment: When you start your Activity you somewhere call intent.putExtra(). Just call it for each variable. And call getIntent().getSerializableExtra(extraIdentifier) for each variable.